# How to solve this query in sql server by using self join(which I think so) and not using subqueries and nested?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

The employees who have the same branch are colleagues of each other. You need to write a query that can give you the colleagues of EmpId 'x' and the list of the colleagues should not include the user 'x' himself. For eg:- If x = 4 then the result should be EmpId 1 and 5.

**Note:- You have to do it using only one query. No nested queries or subqueries are allowed.**
[this is the table of above problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xArMm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Id,(t2.Id),t2.branch From Employee as t1 ,Employee as t2 
where  t1.branch=t2.branch and t1.Id != t2.Id
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT t2.* From [dbo].[EmpTest] as t1 ,[dbo].[EmpTest] as t2 
WHERE t1.EmpId=4 and t1.branch=t2.branch and t2.EmpId<>4

Result:-
EmpId   branch
1        D
5        D
```

Comment: But if I want data orderly wise of all the colleagues for all the branches orderly-wise without writing empid=4 because if I will be having data of 2000 rows then i will not write empid=4 or will not pick empid randomly and search for data.

Comment: the data I want should be for all the branches orderly wise

Comment: Without providing empid=x values, how query identify you for remove from the colleague list? For order, you can use 'order by t2. branch'. If this is not your question then please provide some sample data and expected output.